# how to hide custom title background image?

Tags: android, image, background, hide, title

In my program, sometimes , I need to hide my custom title,but I failed hide the tilte's background image.the button and the Textview I can hide well. my code(xml) as follow.

the title xml : viewimage_slide_title.xml

```
< RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/iphone_header_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/viewimage_slide_title">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/third_image_button_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/third_title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the style.xml:

```
       <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
       <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
           <item name="android:background">@drawable/iphone_header_bg</item>
        </style>

       <style
            name="title" parent="android:Theme.Light">
           <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item><item                                                       name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
          </style>
```

the manifes.xml . the activity. i add as:

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.android.camera.third.MianActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/view_label"
        android:theme="@style/title"
        android:screenOrientation="behind" >
```

In my java(MianActivity) code:

```
titlebar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewimage_slide_title);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.viewimage_slide);

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.viewimage_slide_title);
```

In my other java code:
I do

```
 MianActivity.titlebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: so you aren't able to hide iphone_header_bg image.

Comment: can you please show you complete xml code and java code...

Comment: what you want to hide ..did not get

Comment: If you want us to help you, then you need to provide us with adequate details. Without it, we are sometimes helpless, even if we are capable to answer your question or doubts.

Comment: declare titlebar to public static or use interface

Comment: they are too much code in my program, i just can paste part code

Comment: I can not hide  iphone_header_bg, but I can hide the button and textview. In my program.

Answer (score 1):

Add one ParentLayout in your XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_heigth="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/iphone_header_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/viewimage_slide_title">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/third_image_button_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/third_title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to remove your backgroundImage then use,

```
titlebar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
titlebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: You're correct. But i think @user1645800 is showing the xml code without parent layout.

Comment: ya may be he/she can.. But from @user1645800 question this is one solution .. if he/she edit the questions means we improve our answer :)

Comment: thank you~~ I try it , but the results is same, can not hide the background image.

Comment: At first i forget add this titlebar.setBackground(null);

Comment: MianActivity.titlebar.setBackground(null); cannot find the method setBackground()

Comment: use setBackgroundDrawable(null);

Comment: all the three method i try it, the set color method is misorder(i am not understand ), other metods has nothing to do about it .   //MianActivity.titlebar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    //MianActivity.titlebar.setBackgroundResource(0);
    MianActivity.titlebar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

Comment: try titlebar.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);

Comment: Hi,friend,I find if I remove android:background="@drawable/iphone_header_bg"   in my viewimage_slide_title.xml , then still work,because in my Activity ,I set the theme( android:theme="@style/title") ,then it's background image is  iphone_header_bg , so what I need is to change the theme backgroud, not the tiltebar. Maybe I should change my theme.

Answer (score 0):

First Of all , what do you mean by custom title bar?
Second thing is what i have understood by your code is you want to hide a layout ( viewimage_slide_title.xml) .

For this you simple provide a id to the Relative layout and set visibility gone to  the layout rather than the button or textview .

You are able to hide button and text view but failed to hide  tilte's background image because background set to relative layout not to button or text.

here is code  -

```
<RelativeLayout
android:background="@drawable/iphone_header_bg"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/viewimage_slide_title">

<Button
android:id="@+id/third_image_button_back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/third_title_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then your main Activity : -

```
titlebar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewimage_slide_title);

MianActivity.titlebar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: hi,In my code , your paste the code the same with me,but I can not did

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason , because  both the theme (title) and  layout   I set the backgroud, it is wrong,where I change my theme, so it work. thanks guys for  these help me ~~  this is my first  question in stackoverflow.